# Insterstial ad doesn't diplay when button back pressed

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Hi all I want to show interstial ad when user press back button 
**this is my code in the activity.xml :**

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**and in the class activity.java :**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: remove `if...else` condition

Comment: you need to load ad before displaying, you are doing all the things when back button is clicked. instead you should preload ads to display immediately

Comment: if I remove if ...else :it will display error and the application stop

Comment: follow the guide here :https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see you are initializing and loading ads in `onBackPressed()` method. so, every time it doesn't gets loaded instantly. So, initialize and load your ad in `onCreate()` and in `onBackPressed()` check if ad is loaded then show your ad.

Inside `onCreate()` do like this:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
```

and inside `onBackPressed()` do like this:

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Also, interstitial ads doesn't need xml element so, remove AdView from xml.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize admob inside `onCreate` and then load add first ,call `mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());` method after setting addunit Id
You Also not need to add `AdView` inside xml if you only want to show interstitial ad

Answer (score 0):

**Change in `onCreate()`:**

```
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Code to be executed when when the interstitial ad is closed.
        finish();
    }
});
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

**change your code as per my suggestion in `onBackPressed()`:**

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    mInterstitialAd.show();

}else{
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**and InterstitialAd does not need xml view, so remove that**